# Пунктирная рамка вокруг картинок-ссылок в IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Подскажите, как можно убрать пунктирную рамку вокруг картинок-ссылок, появляющуюся при наведении в ие7 ?
[image]
в ие8 и ие9 помогло прописать в стилях

```
a:active, a:focus, img { 
    outline: none;
    }
```

но в ие7 это не работает.
как можно это решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, в ие7 помог такой скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').focus(
    function(){
    this.blur();
    });
    });
</script>
```

если есть еще какие-нибудь варианты решения, будет интересно узнать :)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше используй атрибут hideFocus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").attr("hideFocus", "true");
});
```

Так ты отключаешь отображение пунктирной рамки, но не заставляешь элемент терять фокус. Он может понадобиться в некоторых случаях.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас опробую этот способ! а в каких случая может понадобится оставить фокус у элемента?

Comment: К примеру при навигации с клавиатуры? Табуляцией дойти до нужной ссылки и нажать энтер? Или же если у вас выполняются какие-то скрипты при фокусе элемента. Вы выше сбрасываете фокус и это может помешать другим скриптам которым может фокус понадобиться. Сложно придумывать сферические примеры :)

Comment: ясно) спасибо за объяснения)